# Filter an array nested with an object

Tags: javascript

Get an element inside an array based on a condition using find is known to me, but what if array is nested with an object?

```js
[{
    _id: 1,
    crew: [{
        name: "A",
        price: "5",
      },
      {
        name: "B",
        price: "10",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    crew: [{
        name: "C",
        price: "15",
      },
      {
        name: "D",
        price: "20",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I want to search by name, let **D** be an example
Expected result

```js
{
  name: "D",
  price: "20",
},
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try this out

```
response.find(el => el.crew?.find(el => el.name === "D")).crew.find(el => el.name === "D")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
arr.find((obj) => {
   return obj.crew.some((cr) => {
     return cr.name === 'D'
 }
})
```